# Text with Text.DateStyle in SwiftUI View in Complication alignment

Tags: swiftui, watchos, clockkit

I want to create a complication rendered by a SwiftUI View that contains a label and a timer value.

I want the label to be on the complication background layer, and the timer value to be on the complication foreground layer so that they get tinted separately.

I would like this line of text, comprised of 2 parts, to be centered.

The trouble is, when using Text.DateStyle.timer, the Text behaves differently within a complication vs in a normal view.

In a normal view the Text frame behaves as any other text, only taking the space it needs.

When displayed in a complication, the Text frame expands to fill all the space it can, and the text within is left aligned.

This makes it so I cannot find a way to center the group of 2 Texts.

I tried a somewhat hacky approach with infinite spacers to try to steal the extra space from the Text that has the expanding frame. This works to center the content, but it causes the Text to truncate.

```swift
HStack {
    Text("T:")
        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)

    Text(Date(), style: .timer)
        .complicationForeground()
}

HStack {
    Spacer()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

    HStack {
        Text("T:")
            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)

        Text(Date(), style: .timer)
            .complicationForeground()
    }

    Spacer()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
}
```

**A normal preview:**

[image]

**A preview of rendering within complication:**

```swift
CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicExtraLargeCircularView(
    ExtraLargeStack()
)
.previewContext(faceColor: .multicolor)
```

[image]

---

### Edit to show full code

```swift
import ClockKit
import SwiftUI

struct ExtraLargeStack: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            HStack {
                Text("T:")
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)

                Text(Date(), style: .timer)
                    .complicationForeground()
            }

            HStack {
                Spacer()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

                HStack {
                    Text("T:")
                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)

                    Text(Date(), style: .timer)
                        .complicationForeground()
                }

                Spacer()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }
        .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .regular))
        .lineLimit(1)
    }
}

struct ExtraLargeStack_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        /// Preview normal view
        // ExtraLargeStack()
        
        /// Preview as Complication
        CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicExtraLargeCircularView(
            ExtraLargeStack()
        )
        .previewContext(faceColor: .multicolor)
    }
}
```

---

### Edit: Another partial solution

Based on suggestions from @Yrb, an overlay provides a partial solution that may be good enough for my use case.

The following does not fully center the 2 part line, but it is pretty close.

```swift
HStack {
    // Use placeholder text to create a view with the appropriate size for _most_ timer values that I need to support
    Text("L: 00:00 ").hidden()
}
.overlay(
    // overlay the real content, which is constrained to the frame created by the hidden placeholder.
    HStack(spacing: 5) {
        Text("L:")
            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)

        Text(Date() - 3599, style: .timer)
            .complicationForeground()
    }
)
```

Comment: Can you show the whole view struct? The code you have posted is would not evaluate to what is shown. They would have to have an enclosing stack.

Comment: @Yrb , edited question to include the full code.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out what the issue with aligning `Text(Date(), style: .timer)` is. The timer format from hours on down. The document give this as an example: `2:59 36:59:01`. It appears that `.timer` reserves all of the possible space it needs and then is formatted on that possible space, not the space actually used. There does not appear to be any way to change this behavior, even if your goal is a 5 minute countdown timer.

I think you need to consider slight UI change. I did find that you can change the alignment of the displayed `Text` with a `.timer` by using `.multilineTextAlignment()`, but that is about all you can do. The following code demonstrates this:

```
struct ExtraLargeStack: View {
    var body: some View {
        // I removed (alignment: .center) as it is redundant. VStacks default to center
        VStack {
            // I put the negative spacing to tighten the T: with the timer
            VStack(spacing: -6) {
                Text("T:")
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                
                Text(Date(), style: .timer)
                    // If you center with .multilineTextAlignment the timer
                    // will be centered
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .complicationForeground()
            }
            
            HStack {
                 HStack {
                    Text(Date(), style: .timer)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .complicationForeground()
                        .overlay(
                            Text("T:")
                                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                                // This offset would need to be computed
                                .offset(x: -30, y: 0)
                        )
                }
            }
        }
        .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .regular))
    }
}
```

I left the second timer as an `HStack`, but I put your `Text("T")` as an `.overlay()` with a `.offset()`. I don't particularly like this as it will be fragile if you attempt to adjust the offset for the additional time units, but if you have a limited range, it may work well enough. Also, if you use `.monospaced` on the timer text, the computation should be a linear amount.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. While I do appreciate the effort, neither of these solutions will work for me. Changing to stacked centered text isn't acceptable for our design. And, I don't see how I can reliably calculate the necessary offset for the second option. I cannot use .monospaced because I am targeting watchOS 7.

Comment: see my edit above for a partial solution based on your overlay idea. Thanks! Not perfect, but another incremental improvement...

Comment: It was tough as there was no way to tell what your intentions were with regard to display from the code. If you can't use `.monospaced` I would highly recommend keeping the "L", "T" or whatever you will use in the `.overlay, otherwise it will bounce as the digits change.